# How to pass innerHTML for a particular html element through its class in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a code segment that containing similar div(class name is same for all) around 100 but the inside content of each division is different. 
My question is when I click on any division, selected div's content should be passed to the some other div

Ex: div's

```
 <div class="thumbnail">       
          <div class="caption">
            <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
            <p>Cras justo odio, dap id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>          
          </div>
        </div>
     <div class="thumbnail">       
          <div class="caption">
            <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
            <p>Cras justo odio, dap id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>          
          </div>
        </div>
```

This is What I tried using jquery

```
$(function() {
    $('.thumbnail').on('click', function() {
        $('#myModalLabel').html($(this'>h3').html()); // here i am getting trouble please help me out
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to find a descendant of the current element

```
$(this).find('h3').html()
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mix up this reference with other selector directly, you have to use `.find()` function in this context

Try,

```
$('.thumbnail').on('click', function() {
   $('#myModalLabel').html($(this).find('h3').html()); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uU4mk/)**

Use find()

```
 $('.thumbnail').on('click', function() {

alert($(this).find("h3").text());

});
```